# Virtualbox: Windows 10 performance of virtualbox is very slow

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I have recently upgrade the host from windows 7 up to windows 10 and I have noticed that my virtualbox is now 200% slower using an ubuntu guest OS. I have 16 GB of RAM with 4 GB allocated to the VM. I have tried with both 4 cores and 2 cores on the VM still no difference. I have an i7-2600 4 core machine + 4 ht cores.

Is this a known issue? How can I debug this further? I know it is a CPU problem but I am not sure how to resolve this.

I have gathered perfomance metrics for Hyper-V and VirtualBox and it seems that VirtualBox beats Hyper-V in all aspects apart from the CPU which is twice as slow.

Virtualbox https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/12206247

Hyper-V https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/12206485/claim?key=124499

Note: I do notice that the CPU is utilised at 50% (I have assigned 4 out of 4 physical cores), however the performance of the CPU is slow.

Comment: Could you [edit] the post and specify the OS for both the *host* **and** the *guest* in each case? Did you upgrade the *host* from Windows 7 to 10 or the *guest*?

Comment: How much installed memory do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the Virtual box hardening logs there is the log item of:

NtOpenDirectoryObject failed on \Driver: 0xc0000022

After running Virtualbox with administrator rights it seemed to go as fast as normal.
This does seem to be a Virtualbox issue. I have tried this on 3 different machines all running windows 10 as the host and the same error message comes out.

Comment: Hi, in my case running VBox as admin didn't give any improvement.

Comment: In the virtual box logs do you still get this error message?
NtOpenDirectoryObject failed on \Driver: 0xc0000022 ?